# flex-box IE10 doesn't respect overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to create a flexbox with a header and footer of a set height and have a flexible content area that may or may not scroll depending on the amount of content within.

You can see my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/evilbuck/EtQXf/3/

This works in FF, chrome, but not IE10. IE10 seems to not respect the overflow property and bleeds into the content below.

My expectation is that the .content area will expand to fill the remaining space of it's parent and scroll when necessary.

```
<div class="container">
  <header>A header</header>
  <div class="content">Some content that will overflow or not.</div>
  <footer>A footer</footer>
</div>

.container {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;

    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;

    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}



.content {
   flex: 1;
   -webkit-flex: 1;
   -moz-flex: 1;
   -ms-flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave this here for others, but the short of it is that I needed to use

```
display: -ms-flexbox;
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EtQXf/4/